# How to set hyphenation parameters automatically in LuaTeX?

Tags: luatex, hyphenation, discretionary

In the following example we need to hyphenate "aa-aa", but not "bbbb".

How to set `righthyphenmin=2` automatically if all letters of a word are "a", and keep it default for all other cases?

```
\language255
%\righthyphenmin=2
\hyphenation{aa-aa}
\hyphenation{bb-bb}
\parindent=0pt
\hsize=1pt
\hfuzz=100pt
aaaa
bbbb
\bye
```

LuaTeX has `tex.righthyphenmin`. And in the article [LuaTEX: What it takes to make a paragraph](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-1/tb100isambert.pdf), in section "Inserting discretionaries", it is said about `hyphenate` callback. Is it possible to solve this problem using these facilities?

Comment: what is the real problem you are trying to solve? righthyphenmin applies to all words so if it is 3 that will suppresss aa-aa if you want any words to hyphenate after the second letter set it to 2 then add patterns including word start to discourage the break after bb. so righthyphenmin does not seem to be the parameter than you need to set conditionally

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I use the fact that codes of cyrillic and latin characters do not intersect, so I load hyphenation tables for both of them simultaneously, which is very convenient, as it frees from switching the language manually each time. The only issue is that in English righthyphenmin=3, and in russian it is 2. I still haven't found the solution... See UPDATE for the test function that I use.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: IMHO, the problem is interesting in itself and I created this special MWE (because it assumes as little as possible about local setup, so that everyone can run it).

Comment: yes this appears to be an xy-problem asking how to set \righthyhenmin per word when that's almost certainly not the right solution to the actual problem. why can't you just add patterns that prevent hyphenation within 2 characters of the end of a word in english (may take a few patterns but you can easily generate the needed list)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Your proposal is interesting, but I have almost found the solution to the first problem. Do you know why the first word in example in UPDATE is not hyphenated?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I mean you want righthyphenmin=2 so cyrillic works then you just need to set patterns for latin letters within 2 of the end of the word to prevent hyphenation in those cases rather than rely of righthyphenmin.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: sorry, I misunderstood at first. Now I corrected my previous comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some full example which loads hyphenation patterns for requested languages and can detect used language from characters unicode values.

Simple Lua library `languages.lua` is used:

```
kpse.set_program_name "luatex"
local M = {}
local languages = require "language.dat"
M.languages = languages
local ranges = {default = "english"}



local function load_patterns(pat)
  if not pat then return "" end
  local fname = kpse.find_file(pat)
  if not fname then return "" end
  local file = io.open(fname, "r")
  local patterns = file:read("*all")
  file:close()
  return patterns or ""
end

function M.get_lang(l) 
  local language = languages[l] 
  if not language then return nil end
  local id= language.id
  -- English is built in
  if l == "english" then id = 0 end 
  if id then return language end
  local langobj = lang.new()
  id = lang.id(langobj)
  local patterns = load_patterns(language.patterns)
  lang.patterns(langobj,patterns)
  language.id = id
  languages[l] = language
  return language
end

local function convert_num(num)
  if type(num) == "number" then return num end
  return tonumber(num, 16)
end

function M.add_range(lang, min, max)
  print("add range", lang, min, max)

  ranges[#ranges+1] = {lang = lang, min = convert_num(min), max = convert_num(max)}
end

function M.default(lang)
  ranges.default = lang
end

function M.test_range(ucode)
  for _,v in ipairs(ranges) do
    local min = v.min
    local max = v.max
    if ucode >= min and ucode  <= max then
      return v.lang
    end
  end
  return ranges.default
end

return M
```

this library loads file `language.dat.lua`, which is table with various information about languages:

```
 ['russian'] = {
    loader = 'loadhyph-ru.tex',
    lefthyphenmin = 2,
    righthyphenmin = 2,
    synonyms = {  },
    patterns = 'hyph-ru.pat.txt',
    hyphenation = 'hyph-ru.hyp.txt',
  },
```

useful information are `patterns` and `righthyphenmin` fields. We must load patterns using `lang.patterns` function, in order to get the hyphenation to work.

We need some helper macros from TeX side, `minilang.tex`:

```
\directlua{
languages = require "languages"
}

\def\loadlang#1{%
\directlua{languages.get_lang "#1"}%
}

\def\definerange#1#2#3{%
\directlua{languages.add_range("#1","#2","#3")}%
}

\def\defaultrange#1{\directlua{languages.default "#1"}}

\directlua{
  local GLYF = node.id("glyph")
  local uchar  = unicode.utf8.char
  function show_nodes (head)
    for item in node.traverse(head) do
      local i = item.id
      if i == GLYF then
        local langname = languages.test_range(item.char)
        local l = languages.get_lang(langname) or {}
        item.lang = l.id
        item.right = l.righthyphenmin
        item.left = l.lefthyphenmin
      end
      % texio.write(i .. " ")
    end 
    return head
  end

  luatexbase.add_to_callback("hyphenate",
    function (head, tail)
      head = show_nodes(head)
      % tex.righthyphenmin=2
      lang.hyphenate(head)
      return head
    end, "find script")

luatexbase.add_to_callback("pre_linebreak_filter", function(head)
  for n in node.traverse(head) do
    if n.id == GLYF then
      print(uchar(n.char), n.lang, n.right)
    end
  end
  return head
end, "print nodes")
}
```

macro `\loadlang` defines new language, `\definerange` defines unicode range for a language and `\defaultrange` defines language to be used when character doens't match defined ranges.

modified `hyphenate` callback from your test file is used, we use `languages.test_range(item.char)` to get character's language, then load language data using `languages.get_lang` and set node `lang` and `right` fields to correct values from language data.

Some full sample:

```
\nopagenumbers
\input luaotfload.sty

\font\libertine= {Linux Libertine O} at 10pt
\libertine
\input minilang.tex
\loadlang{russian}
\loadlang{english}
\definerange{russian}{0400}{052F}
\defaultrange{english}
\wlog{the language: \the\language}
%\righthyphenmin=2
\hyphenation{aa-aa}
\hyphenation{bb-bb}
\parindent=0pt
\hsize=6em
\hfuzz=100pt

The development of Cyrillic typography passed directly from the medieval stage to the late Baroque, without a Renaissance phase as in Western Europe. Late Medieval Cyrillic letters (still found on many icon inscriptions today) show a marked tendency to be very tall and narrow, with strokes often shared between adjacent letters.

Peter the Great, Czar of Russia, mandated the use of westernized letter forms in the early 18th century. Over time, these were largely adopted in the other languages that use the script. Thus, unlike the majority of modern Greek fonts that retained their own set of design principles for lower-case letters (such as the placement of serifs, the shapes of stroke ends, and stroke-thickness rules, although Greek capital letters do use Latin design principles), modern Cyrillic fonts are much the same as modern Latin fonts of the same font family. The development of some Cyrillic computer typefaces from Latin ones has also contributed to the visual Latinization of Cyrillic type.

Около 863братья Константин (Кирилл) Философ и Мефодий из Солуни (Салоники) по приказу византийского императора Михаила III упорядочили письменность для старославянского языка и использовали новую азбуку для перевода на славянский язык греческих религиозных текстов[2]:44. Долгое время дискуссионным оставался вопрос, была ли это кириллица (и в таком случае глаголицу считают тайнописью, появившейся после запрещения кириллицы) или глаголица — азбуки, различающиеся почти исключительно начертанием. В настоящее время в науке преобладает точка зрения, согласно которой глаголица первична, а кириллица вторична (в кириллице глаголические буквы заменены на известные греческие). Так, большинство учёных склонны считать, что глаголицу создал Константин (Кирилл) Философ, а кириллицу — его ученик Климент Охридский[3]. Глаголица длительное время в несколько изменённом виде употреблялась у хорватов (до XVII в).
bbbb
\bye
```

we must use `luaotfload` with suitable opentype font to get cyrillic script. Important part is:

```
\input minilang.tex
\loadlang{russian}
\loadlang{english}
\definerange{russian}{0400}{052F}
\defaultrange{english}
```

which defines characters in unicode range  `0400..052F` to use Russian language. Values to be used in `\definerange` can be found in [unicode blocks document](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/Blocks.txt).

The result:

[image]

Comment: I cannot make ` ` and `''` ligatures work in libertine. Do you know why they do not work?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko because these aren't ligatures provided by the font. it is provided by `luaotfload` as `tlig` feature, you can enable it using `\font\libertine="Linux Libertine O Italic":+tlig at 10pt`

Answer (score 0):

The following code works as required:

```
callback.register("hyphenate",
  function (head, tail)
    for item in node.traverse(head) do
      if item.id == node.id("glyph") and item.char > 1025 and item.char < 1105 then
        item.right=2
      end
    end
    lang.hyphenate(head)
  end)
```